# Suppress logging of specific servlet filter exceptions in WebSphere

Tags: java, exception, servlets, logging, websphere

I have several servlet filters that throw exceptions in certain situations, e.g. when user authorization fails. Some of these exceptions get thrown quite regularly and therefore tend to flood WebSphere's log.

Is there any way to keep WebSphere from logging these exceptions? The class logging the exceptions is `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp`. Lowering the log level for it to disable logging, would mean I'd also miss important exceptions. I just want to exclude a few select exceptions from being logged.

I'm using WebSphere 8.5.5 with fix pack 5. The exceptions I'm trying to suppress are runtime exceptions. I tried changing them to checked `javax.servlet.ServletException`s, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Comment: No, there seems to be no way to do this. Just use your preferred logging library, create your own log file and ignore WebSphere's log as much as possible.